sh script not running inside a alpine:3.12 container when created from the image, but it is running when manually triggered inside the pod
Here is the Dockerfile I have used:
FROM alpine:3.12
RUN apk add --no-cache util-linux python3 py3-pip
RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash

COPY 1#check_dmesg_logs.sh /usr/local/bin/check-dmesg-logs.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/check-dmesg-logs.sh

CMD ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/check-dmesg-logs.sh"]

Below is the script I'm trying to run:
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    dmesg | grep -i 'nfs' 
    dmesg | grep -i 'rpc'
    sleep 10
done

Error:
/usr/local/bin/check-dmesg-logs.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected "done" (expecting "do")

Does the script file have DOS/Windows-style line endings? That'd cause exactly this error. See "Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?" and "Why is a shell script giving syntax errors when the same code works elsewhere?" BTW, it looks like the shell you're using is dash, not bash; they're similar, but not quite the same.

You are correct, seems like it resolved when I converted the file using the command - dos2unix <myscript.sh> as explained here why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere . Thank you Gordon so much for the help.

Btw, you can search for both protocols in one go with grep -Ei "nfs|rpc"

Or even grep -Fi -e 'nfs' -e 'rpc'

Tangentially, Difference between sh and bash
